# Primefaces Autocomplete - How to display dropdown items on click of input

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Using PF 4/5 and Mojarra 2.2

I have an autocomplete field with a dropdown being shown. The list of items displays when I click the dropdown or start typing in the input. I want the list of items to display when the input box gets focus so that essentially I can remove the dropdown button image. Im not sure how to trigger that.

```
<p:autoComplete minQueryLength="0" size="7" queryDelay="0" dropdown="true" scrollHeight="200" value="#{scheduleView.startTime}" id="startTime"  completeMethod="#{scheduleView.getTimes}" required="true" onclick="this.select()">
```

Comment: it will work when you start typing, but when it get focus? are you sure you want that?

Comment: you may find this option useful too -- forceSelection="true"

Comment: Yes it definitely works when I start typing. And yes I want it to display onfocus or onclick of the input field, without typing so the user can chose to type or just make a selection from the list. Maybe it's not possible.

Comment: you can have a select box with autocomplete too -- http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml

Comment: Yep, that is what I am using but does not show drop down on focus of the input box. It only shows the dropdown when clicking the dropdown icon. So I am not sure how to call the "dropdown.show()" when the input gets focus...

Answer (score 4):

You can trigger client side's `search()` function on autocomplete input click :

```
<p:autoComplete
    id="startTime"
    widgetVar="foo"
    value="#{scheduleView.startTime}"
    completeMethod="#{scheduleView.getTimes}"
    required="true"
    dropdown="true"
    size="7"
    scrollHeight="200"
    minQueryLength="0"
    queryDelay="0"
    onclick="PF('foo').search(PF('foo').input.val());">
```