# primeng autocomplete no onSelect event on click

Tags: angular, primeng

I expected that the PrimeNG AutoComplete component is emitting the (onSelect) event on and on Keyboard select. But it emits only Keyboard selection. 
While "[dropdown]=false"

The Example is very simple:

```
<p-autoComplete ... (onSelect)="onSelect()" ...>
```

...

```
onSelect(){
    console.log('select', this.suggestions);
  }
```

using:
"primeng": "^6.1.4",
"@angular/cli": "^6.2.3",

How do I catch a clicked selection on auto-complete suggestions?

Or even better:
How can I achieve the "DropdownButton-click" behavior on "InputField-click"?
Just to get rid of the dropdown button but keep the behavior.

EDIT:

Its similar to this case, but it doesnt helps me for the Angular way.

[Primefaces Autocomplete - How to display dropdown items on click of input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897898/primefaces-autocomplete-how-to-display-dropdown-items-on-click-of-input)

Answer (score 4):

I confirm that this works for me on Angular8/PrimeNG8 ("primeng": "^8.0.0",     "@angular/cli": "^8.3.25"). Both when selecting using the mouse or the keyboard: the onSelect gets triggered.

Make sure you pass the event as well:

```
<p-autoComplete ... (onSelect)="onSelect($event)" ...>
```

...

```
onSelect(event: any){
    console.log( event );
  }
```

Check "frosty"'s solution/stackblitz. That works.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get this to work in a stack blitz. The `onSelect` works, as well as the `completeMethod` works.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7komnz

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the `[(ngModel)]="selectedIem"`